# rlang::hash cannot differentiate between arrow queries

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, apache-arrow, memoise

I use the `memoise` package to cache queries to an `arrow` dataset but I sometimes get mismatches/"collisions" in hashes and therefore the wrong values are returned.

I have isolated the problem and replicated it in the MWE below.
The issue is that the `rlang::hash()` (which `memoise` uses) of an arrow query that first filters then summarises does not depend on the filter.

My question is: is this something that I can fix (because I used it wrongly) or is this a bug in the one of the packages (I am happy to create an issue), if so, should this be reported to `arrow`, `rlang::hash()`, or even `R6`?

### MWE

For example, all three queries below have the same hash but **they should be different** (and looking at the results, the results obviously are...)

```r
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

ds_file <- file.path(tempdir(), "mtcars")

write_dataset(mtcars, ds_file)
ds <- open_dataset(ds_file)

# 1) Create three different queries =======

# Query 1 with mpg > 25 ----
query1 <- ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 25) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

# Query 2 with mpg > 0 ----
query2 <- ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 0) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

# Query 3 with filter on cyl ----
query3 <- ds |> 
  filter(cyl == 4) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg))


# 2) Lets compare the hashes: the main issue ======
rlang::hash(query1)
#> [1] "f505339fd65df6ef53728fcc4b0e55f7"
rlang::hash(query2)
#> [1] "f505339fd65df6ef53728fcc4b0e55f7"
rlang::hash(query3)
#> [1] "f505339fd65df6ef53728fcc4b0e55f7"
# ERROR HERE: they should be different as the queries are different!

# 3) Lets also compare the results: clearly different =====
query1 |> collect()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      vs     n mean_mpg
#>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     30.9
#> 2     0     1     26

query2 |> collect()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      vs     n mean_mpg
#>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
#> 1     0    18     16.6
#> 2     1    14     24.6

query3 |> collect()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      vs     n mean_mpg
#>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
#> 1     1    10     26.7
#> 2     0     1     26
```

Note that the same error happens when I use `digest`.

When I print the queries, they are printed as if they were identical... (I reported this bug [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/14732) to arrow)

```
query1
#> FileSystemDataset (query)
#> vs: double
#> n: int32
#> mean_mpg: double
#> 
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object

query2
#> FileSystemDataset (query)
#> vs: double
#> n: int32
#> mean_mpg: double
#> 
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object

query3
#> FileSystemDataset (query)
#> vs: double
#> n: int32
#> mean_mpg: double
#> 
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object
```

but when I query the `$.data` argument of the query, I see that they are in fact different

```
query1$.data
#> FileSystemDataset (query)
#> mpg: double
#> vs: double
#> 
#> * Aggregations:
#> n: sum(1)
#> mean_mpg: mean(mpg)
#> * Filter: (mpg > 25)            #<=========
#> * Grouped by vs
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object

query2$.data
#> FileSystemDataset (query)
#> mpg: double
#> vs: double
#> 
#> * Aggregations:
#> n: sum(1)
#> mean_mpg: mean(mpg)
#> * Filter: (mpg > 0)             #<=========
#> * Grouped by vs
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object

query3$.data
#> FileSystemDataset (query)
#> mpg: double
#> vs: double
#> 
#> * Aggregations:
#> n: sum(1)
#> mean_mpg: mean(mpg)
#> * Filter: (cyl == 4)            #<=========
#> * Grouped by vs
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object
```

but again `rlang::hash()` cannot find a difference:

```
rlang::hash(query1$.data)
#> [1] "b7f743cd635f7dc06356b827a6974df8"
rlang::hash(query2$.data)
#> [1] "b7f743cd635f7dc06356b827a6974df8"
rlang::hash(query3$.data)
#> [1] "b7f743cd635f7dc06356b827a6974df8"
```

If it helps, the query objects are `R6` objects with class `arrow_dplyr_query` (see also its [source code in apache/arrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/5e53978b56aa13f9c033f2e849cc22f2aed6e2d3/r/R/dplyr.R))

### Memoise use case

For completeness sake and to put the problem into perspective, I use the following to cache the results, which should return different values (see above) but doesn't!

```r
library(arrow)
library(memoise)
library(dplyr)

ds_file <- file.path(tempdir(), "mtcars")

write_dataset(mtcars, ds_file)
ds <- open_dataset(ds_file)

collect_cached <- memoise::memoise(dplyr::collect,
                                   cache = cachem::cache_mem(logfile = stdout()))

# Query 1 with mpg > 25 ----
ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 25) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) |> 
  collect_cached()
#> [2022-11-25 09:16:28.586] cache_mem get: key "2edd901226498414056dcc54eaa49415"
#> [2022-11-25 09:16:28.586] cache_mem get: key "2edd901226498414056dcc54eaa49415" is missing
#> [2022-11-25 09:16:28.705] cache_mem set: key "2edd901226498414056dcc54eaa49415"
#> [2022-11-25 09:16:28.706] cache_mem prune
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      vs     n mean_mpg
#>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     30.9
#> 2     0     1     26

# Query 2 with mpg > 0 ----
# this is wrongly matched to the first query and returns wrong results... 
ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 0) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) |> 
  collect_cached()
#> [2022-11-25 09:16:28.820] cache_mem get: key "2edd901226498414056dcc54eaa49415"
#> [2022-11-25 09:16:28.820] cache_mem get: key "2edd901226498414056dcc54eaa49415" found    #< ERROR HERE! as the hash is identical
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>      vs     n mean_mpg
#>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     30.9
#> 2     0     1     26
```

Note that we get the same result although the queries are different (yet their hashes are identical, hence this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very much a hack ... but perhaps it'll be enough? I was able to find something unique-enough about the intermediate "query" that included its filter components by capturing the output from `show_query`, and using that as the `hash=` argument to `memoise`:

```r
hashfun <- function(x) {
  x$x <- capture.output(show_query(x$x))
  rlang::hash(x)
}
collect_cached <- memoise::memoise(
  dplyr::collect,
  cache = cachem::cache_mem(logfile = stdout()),
  hash = hashfun)

ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 25) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) |> 
  collect_cached()
# [2022-11-25 08:14:56.596] cache_mem get: key "e6184e282e05875139e8afd2a071f329"
# [2022-11-25 08:14:56.596] cache_mem get: key "e6184e282e05875139e8afd2a071f329" is missing
# [2022-11-25 08:14:56.616] cache_mem set: key "e6184e282e05875139e8afd2a071f329"
# [2022-11-25 08:14:56.616] cache_mem prune
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      vs     n mean_mpg
#   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
# 1     1     5     30.9
# 2     0     1     26  

#### different filter, should be a "miss"
ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 0) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) |> 
  collect_cached()
# [2022-11-25 08:15:06.745] cache_mem get: key "88312b31b29050ff029900f4dfc58a9f"
# [2022-11-25 08:15:06.745] cache_mem get: key "88312b31b29050ff029900f4dfc58a9f" is missing
# [2022-11-25 08:15:06.767] cache_mem set: key "88312b31b29050ff029900f4dfc58a9f"
# [2022-11-25 08:15:06.767] cache_mem prune
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      vs     n mean_mpg
#   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
# 1     0    18     16.6
# 2     1    14     24.6

#### repeat of filter `mpg > 0`, should be a "hit"
ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 0) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) |> 
  collect_cached()
# . + > 
# [2022-11-25 08:15:24.825] cache_mem get: key "88312b31b29050ff029900f4dfc58a9f"
# [2022-11-25 08:15:24.825] cache_mem get: key "88312b31b29050ff029900f4dfc58a9f" found
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      vs     n mean_mpg
#   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
# 1     0    18     16.6
# 2     1    14     24.6
```

The object passed to `hashfun` is a list, where the first argument appears to be a checksum or salt of a sort (we'll ignore it), and all remaining arguments (named or otherwise) are determined by the formals of the cached function. In our case, since we're caching `collect`, it accepts `x=` (which we see) and `...=` (which we don't):

```r
debugonce(hashfun)
ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 0) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) |> 
  collect_cached()
# debugging in: encl$`_hash`(c(encl$`_f_hash`, args, lapply(encl$`_additional`, 
#     function(x) eval(x[[2L]], environment(x)))))
# debug at #1: {
#     x$x <- capture.output(show_query(x$x))
#     rlang::hash(x)
# }

x
# [[1]]
# [1] "1e4b92a7ebe8b4bcb1afbd44c9a72a72"
# 
# $x
# FileSystemDataset (query)
# vs: double
# n: int32
# mean_mpg: double
# 
# See $.data for the source Arrow object

show_query(x$x)
# ExecPlan with 6 nodes:
# 5:SinkNode{}
#   4:ProjectNode{projection=[vs, n, mean_mpg]}
#     3:GroupByNode{keys=["vs"], aggregates=[
#       hash_sum(n, {skip_nulls=true, min_count=1}),
#       hash_mean(mean_mpg, {skip_nulls=false, min_count=0}),
#     ]}
#       2:ProjectNode{projection=["n": 1, "mean_mpg": mpg, vs]}
#         1:FilterNode{filter=(mpg > 0)}
#           0:SourceNode{}
```

Just replacing `x$x` with the return from `show_query(x$x)` didn't seem to work since there appear to be things only in the `print`ed form that are not readily available to `rlang::hash`, so I chose `capture.output`.

Comment: I found that this will not depend on the file or the filename. I included either a `tools::md5sum()` or just a call to `gsub(getwd(), "", x$x$files)` to get the filenames (without path to project...) included in the hash calculation. Otherwise different files with the same structure will be a cache missmatch.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my testing, `ds$files` exists, but it goes away the moment we "do something" (such as `filter(..)`). We can sometimes use `.. %>% mutate(f = arrow::add_filename()) %>% distinct(f)` to get at the filenames, but that doesn't work after an aggregating call (i.e., `summarize`). I see no way to get to the filename in a way that is robust to the type of filter/summarize done previously in the pipeline. Sorry @David, I don't know how best to add it atm. I'll continue to think about it, though ... but you might need to look into other caching methods.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that error out! That is indeed the case for me as well!

Comment: What worked for me (tbh, a very stupid hack) is to add a unique query to each dataset. Eg. `ds1 |> filter(1 == 1)`, `ds2 |> filter(2 == 2)` and so on, to distinguish ds1 and ds2

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: See comments this does not work!**

I have modified your MWE below to call $.data or explain on the query which  both do not evaluate the query (pretty sure for .data, 100% for explain) but seem to change the R6 enough to create unique hashes. As you have opened an issue for the underlying problem over at GitHub, this should be a pretty simple workaround with no performance hit.

```
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

ds_file <- file.path(tempdir(), "mtcars")

write_dataset(mtcars, ds_file)
ds <- open_dataset(ds_file)

# 1) Create three different queries =======

# Query 1 with mpg > 25 ----
query1 <- ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 25) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

# Query 2 with mpg > 0 ----
query2 <- ds |> 
  filter(mpg > 0) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

# Query 3 with filter on cyl ----
query3 <- ds |> 
  filter(cyl == 4) |> 
  group_by(vs) |> 
  summarise(n = n(), mean_mpg = mean(mpg))

query1$.data
#> FileSystemDataset (query)
#> mpg: double
#> vs: double
#> 
#> * Aggregations:
#> n: sum(1)
#> mean_mpg: mean(mpg)
#> * Filter: (mpg > 25)
#> * Grouped by vs
#> See $.data for the source Arrow object
explain(query2)
#> ExecPlan with 6 nodes:
#> 5:SinkNode{}
#>   4:ProjectNode{projection=[vs, n, mean_mpg]}
#>     3:GroupByNode{keys=["vs"], aggregates=[
#>      hash_sum(n, {skip_nulls=true, min_count=1}),
#>      hash_mean(mean_mpg, {skip_nulls=false, min_count=0}),
#>     ]}
#>       2:ProjectNode{projection=["n": 1, "mean_mpg": mpg, vs]}
#>         1:FilterNode{filter=(mpg > 0)}
#>           0:SourceNode{}
# 2) Lets compare the hashes: the main issue ======
rlang::hash(query1)
#> [1] "8bbf29208ccbc95fc1bc46f2f2dfe10d"
rlang::hash(query2)
#> [1] "ae5c80b8ed0cc884df40926f3a985b27"
rlang::hash(query3)
#> [1] "3826d824e4c9be046ac5f09dcb60959d"
```

Comment: `explain(.)` doesn't work; if you define all three `query[123]`, then do `explain(query1);explain(query2);explain(query3)`, you'll see that `rlang::hash(query1); rlang::hash(query2); rlang::hash(query3)` has changed but is still invariant. Similarly, if you do `query1$.data; query2$.data; query3$.data`, the hash changes but is still invariant. It's a good thought, though!

Comment: (The reason you see three different hashes at the end of your code is that you call `$.data` on one, `explain(.)` on another, and leave the third untouched.)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for testing. The issue is with `serialize` which `rlang::hash` uses internally. I am guessing that the issue is that the R6 object is just a collection of pointers to arrow-cpp which is then updated by calling `explain` etc.. (unserializing a query does not work with `external pointer to null`) So this will likley be fixed by correcting the print method for queries...